# Warning system, getting the reason(includes discord.js, quick.db)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I want to know how I can get the reason and when I do .warnings @user it says the amount of warnings and reason. I have the amount of warnings clear, but not the reason. When I run this code it says "Foot has 4 warning the reasons is [object Object]" Foot is my account btw.

I've tried db.fetch()
I've tried db.add()
I've tried db.get(`reason_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}_${reason}`;

To be honest I don't know what I am doing wrong. It would be great if you guys helped :)

```
// This file is called warnings.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db');

    
module.exports = {
    name: "warnings",
    description: "Check a users warnings",

    async run (client, message, args){
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.author;
        const prefix = '.'

        let warnings = await db.get(`warnings_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);
        


        let reason = require('./warn') 
        if(warnings === null) warnings = 0;
        
        
        db.get(`reason_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, reason);
        message.channel.send(`**${user.username}** has *${warnings}* warning the reasons is ${reason}`);


        
        


        
    }
}

// This is my warn.js file 

const Discord = require('discord.js');

const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
    name: "warn",
    description: "Warn a member",

    async run (client, message, args) {
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.has('766359629672087603')) return;

        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

        if(!user) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user, via mention or ID');

        if(user.bot) return message.channel.send('You can\'t warn bots');


    const prefix = "."

        var reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified';

        var warnings = db.get(`warnings_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);




        const warnedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#00FF00')
        .setDescription(`${user.username} has been warned`) 
        .setFooter("read rules")

        if(warnings === null) {
            db.set(`warnings_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, 1);
            user.send(warnedEmbed)
            await message.channel.send()
        }

        if(warnings !== null){
            db.add(`warnings_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, 1)
            db.set(`reason_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, reason);
            user.send(`You were warned in ${message.guild.name} for the following reason: \`${reason}\``)
            await message.channel.send(warnedEmbed)
        }



   
       

        
    }
}
```